# Why did this error occur that ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models' ？

Tags: python, yolo

The network structure has already been saved in the best. pt that I trained myself, but why would loading the model in a separate script to execute inference result in an error:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'.

When I execute this script in the official project folder of YOLOv5, it can run successfully.

Can you explain how the customized modules in YOLO are loaded?

If using torch. load, an error will also be reported, and the attempt_load function in the official code must be used。why?

```
`weights="/best.pt"
img_path='2.jpg'

# Load model
model = attempt_load(weights)  # load FP32 model

img = cv2.imread(img_path)
img = cv2.resize(img, (640, 640))
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
img = img[:, :, :, ::-1].transpose(0, 3, 1, 2)
img = np.ascontiguousarray(img)
img = torch.from_numpy(img).to('cpu')
img = img.float()  # uint8 to fp16/32
img /= 255.0  # 0 - 255 to 0.0 - 1.0
if img.ndimension() == 3:
    img = img.unsqueeze(0)
#Is there a simple way to load images?

# # # # Inference
results = model(img)
print(results)`
```

Looking forward to an explanation